# QSystemTrayIcon при нажатии правой кнопкой мыши вешает всю программу python

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, system-tray

Проблема такая, значок в трея выводится, но при нажатии ПКМ мало того, что не показывается меню (меню действий: выйти, скрыть и т.д), но и вешает всю программу и та завершается. Ошибка не выводится в консоль.

Ни кто не знает, в чем трабл? Python 3.7. Модуль `clipWin` это код дизайна. Создан в *QT Designer*

```
icon = 'icon.png'
class ClipApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, clipWin.Ui_MainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super(ClipApp,self).__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint|Qt.WindowTitleHint)
    self.exitBtn.clicked.connect(self.hideClip)
    #инициализация значка трея
    self.tray_icon = QSystemTrayIcon(self)
    self.tray_icon.setIcon(QIcon(icon))
    '''            Объявим и добавим действия для работы с иконкой системного трея
        show - показать окно
        hide - скрыть окно
        exit - выход из программы
    '''
    self.show_action = QAction("Show", self)
    self.quit_action = QAction("Exit", self)
    self.hide_action = QAction("Hide", self)
    self.show_action.triggered.connect(self.show)
    self.hide_action.triggered.connect(self.hideClip)
    self.quit_action.triggered.connect(self.exitClip)
    self.tray_menu = QMenu()
    self.tray_menu.addAction(self.show_action)
    self.tray_menu.addAction(self.hide_action)
    self.tray_menu.addAction(self.quit_action)
    self.tray_icon.setContextMenu(self.tray_menu)
    self.tray_icon.show()

def hideClip(self):
    self.hide()

def exitClip(self):
    self.close()
```

Comment: Дополнительно почитайте здесь: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html#details

Answer (score 1):

1. Вы не опубликовали модуль `clipWin.py`.
2. Что такое `icon` в строке `self.tray_icon.setIcon(QIcon(icon))` ?

А в остальном ваш пример работает как в нем написано.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets    import *
from PyQt5.QtCore       import *
from PyQt5.QtGui        import *


class ClipApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):     #, clipWin.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClipApp, self).__init__()

#        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowTitleHint)

        self.exitBtn = QPushButton("Button", self)
        self.exitBtn.clicked.connect(self.hideClip)

        #инициализация значка трея
        self.tray_icon = QSystemTrayIcon(self)
        self.tray_icon.setIcon(QIcon("im.png"))                              # icon ?

        ''' Объявим и добавим действия для работы с иконкой системного трея
            show - показать окно
            hide - скрыть окно
            exit - выход из программы
        '''
        self.show_action = QAction("Show", self)
        self.quit_action = QAction("Exit", self)
        self.hide_action = QAction("Hide", self)
        self.show_action.triggered.connect(self.show)
        self.hide_action.triggered.connect(self.hideClip)
        self.quit_action.triggered.connect(self.exitClip)

        self.tray_menu = QMenu()
        self.tray_menu.addAction(self.show_action)
        self.tray_menu.addAction(self.hide_action)
        self.tray_menu.addAction(self.quit_action)
        self.tray_icon.setContextMenu(self.tray_menu)
        self.tray_icon.show()

    def hideClip(self):
        self.hide()

    def exitClip(self):
        self.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = ClipApp()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets    import *
from PyQt5.QtCore       import *
from PyQt5.QtGui        import *


class ClipApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):     #, clipWin.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClipApp, self).__init__()

#        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowTitleHint)

        self.exitBtn = QPushButton("Button", self)
        self.exitBtn.clicked.connect(self.hideClip)

        #инициализация значка трея
        self.tray_icon = QSystemTrayIcon(self)
        icon = 'im.png'                                                # <--- +++ 
        self.tray_icon.setIcon(QIcon(icon))

        ''' Объявим и добавим действия для работы с иконкой системного трея
            show - показать окно
            hide - скрыть окно
            exit - выход из программы
        '''
        self.show_action = QAction("Show", self)
        self.quit_action = QAction("Exit", self)
        self.hide_action = QAction("Hide", self)
        self.show_action.triggered.connect(self.show)
        self.hide_action.triggered.connect(self.hideClip)
        self.quit_action.triggered.connect(self.exitClip)

        self.tray_menu = QMenu()
        self.tray_menu.addAction(self.show_action)
        self.tray_menu.addAction(self.hide_action)
        self.tray_menu.addAction(self.quit_action)
        self.tray_icon.setContextMenu(self.tray_menu)
        self.tray_icon.show()

    def hideClip(self):
        self.hide()

    def exitClip(self):
        self.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = ClipApp()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: вопрос дополнил

Comment: в общем icon это путь к png иконке а clipWin это дизайн, созданный в qt designer

Comment: и кстати ваш код у меня не работает тоже, лол)))

Comment: @CyberRik смотрите обновление в ответе.

Comment: да, но это же ничего не меняет в итоге))) видимо у меня проблема с чем-то так как ваш код тоже не работает как надо

Comment: @CyberRik я так предполагаю, что вам пора обновить версию python до 3.7

Comment: думаю да, попробую

Comment: лол, я проверил, у меня версия python 3.7.2

Comment: вы не знаете от чего так может быть?

Comment: данная проблема

Comment: @CyberRik  У меня: 
`python -V` - `Python 3.7.3`
 и 
`from PyQt5 import QtCore` 
`print("PyQt version:", QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR)` 
`PyQt version: 5.12.2`

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо))

Comment: ААА, решение крылось в обновлении pyqt до 5.13

Comment: еще раз спасибо))

Comment: а, нет, рано радовался(( в общем оно 1 раз отрабатывает и то на рандоме(может нет а может да) и все, снова

Comment: так вы не знаете, от чего так может быть?